# In Bitcoin core 0.21 which command replaces getaccountaddress

Tags: bitcoin-core, rpc-error-25

In Bitcoin core 0.21, which command replaces `getaccountaddress`?

Is there any way to get the same data as `getaccountaddress` in 0.21?

Comment: That very much depends on what you were using `getaccountaddress` (and accounts in general for). Depending on the answer to that, there may be solutions that replace it with `getnewaddress`, possibly combined with `setaddresslabel`, separate wallets, or an entirely different custom solution.

Comment: Can give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

> **which command replace getaccountaddress ?**

None, see the notification two and a half years ago in https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.17.0/

| Deprecated Method | New Method | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| getaccount | getaddressinfo | getaddressinfo returns a json object with address information instead of just the name of the account as a string. |
| getaccountaddress | n/a | There is no replacement for getaccountaddress since labels do not have an associated receive address. |
| getaddressesbyaccount | getaddressesbylabel | getaddressesbylabel returns a json object with the addresses as keys, instead of a list of strings. |

etc.

Comment: is there any way to integrate getaccountaddress to new release BTC ?